# Location service based app in android

Tags: android, location

I have developed an android app which checks location updates and sends location data to server after a certain time. I tested both methods; one using Google location apI and another using Android service. But both apps are consuming too much battery. I need to optimise the use of battery, so that users can use the app as long as they need.

There are several apps which track our location all the time and never hamper the battery; for example endomondo, Facebook etc. Specially I want to mention endomondo because it really works fine while working.

Can anyone please suggest me the best way to implement location awareness for android app?

How can I make my app like endomondo or similar location aware app?

Please suggest me the better way to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to reduce the GPS location tracking by check if the LocationManagar has Location that good enough for you?(Maybe other application tracking?)

Ex:

```
    private static Location bestLastKnownLocation(float minAccuracy, long maxAge, LocationManager mLocationManager) {

    Location bestResult = null;
    float bestAccuracy = Float.MAX_VALUE;
    long bestAge = Long.MIN_VALUE;

    List<String> matchingProviders = mLocationManager.getAllProviders();

    for (String provider : matchingProviders) {

        Location location = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        if (location != null) {

            float accuracy = location.getAccuracy();
            long time = location.getTime();

            if (accuracy < bestAccuracy) {

                bestResult = location;
                bestAccuracy = accuracy;
                bestAge = time;

            }
        }
    }

    // Return best reading or null
    if (bestAccuracy > minAccuracy  || (System.currentTimeMillis() - bestAge) > maxAge) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return bestResult;
    }
}
```